# Existing data duplication clean up help

Tags: lightning-community, data, duplicate-management, admin, findduplicates

I'm trying to de-duplicate existing data in SF. I've created and activated matching rules and duplicate rules and checked off reports, yet there is nothing on the "Duplicate Contact Records", when I select contact merge. However when I search a contact potential contacts do show up. Checking every contact is crazy. How do I get the duplicate contact records to reflect existing duplicates? Trying to do a data clean up .

Answer (score 0):

This article describes how to create the duplicate records sets for the Merge tool to use: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.duplicate_management_duplicate_record_sets.htm&type=5